# Wordpress shortcode in RSS feed

Tags: wordpress, rss, shortcode

I'm trying to render shortcodes in my WordPress 4.3 RSS feed, by adding a filter to my theme's `functions.php` like this:

```
add_filter('the_content_feed', 'do_shortcode');
add_filter('the_excerpt_rss', 'do_shortcode');
```

The thing is it doesn't render like it does in the web version, for example for the appbox it shows this: [image: What i see]

instead of this, which i see in the article:
[image]

How can I make it show the same?